# Scala string pattern matching for mathematical symbols

Tags: scala

I have the following code:

```
val z: String = tree.symbol.toString
z match {
  case "method +" | "method -" | "method *" | "method ==" =>
    println("no special op")
    false
  case "method /" | "method %" =>
    println("we have the special div operation")
    true
  case _ =>
    false
}
```

Is it possible to create a match for the primitive operations in Scala:

```
"method *".matches("(method) (+-*==)")
```

I know that the (+-*) signs are used as quantifiers. Is there a way to match them anyway?
Thanks from a avidly Scala scholar!

Comment: matches.matches ? If it is a regular expression you can use something like """method\s+(?:\+|\-|==|)""".r maybe?

Comment: See http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2010/01/regular-expression-3-regex-matching.html

Comment: I don't really understand the question... Are you asking how to escape the special regex characters? (You put a backslash in front of them.) Or are you asking how regular expressions work?

Comment: Yeah I was asking how to escape them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure.

```
val z: String = tree.symbol.toString
val noSpecialOp = "method (?:[-+*]|==)".r
val divOp = "method [/%]".r
z match {
  case noSpecialOp() =>
    println("no special op")
    false
  case divOp() =>
    println("we have the special div operation")
    true
  case _ =>
    false
}
```

Things to consider:

- I choose to match against single characters using `[abc]` instead of `(?:a|b|c)`.
- Note that `-` has to be the first character when using `[]`, or it will be interpreted as a range. Likewise, `^` cannot be the first character inside `[]`, or it will be interpreted as negation.
- I'm using `(?:...)` instead of `(...)` because I don't want to extract the contents. If I *did* want to extract the contents -- so I'd know what was the operator, for instance, then I'd use `(...)`. However, I'd also have to change the matching to *receive* the extracted content, or it would fail the match.
- It is important not to forget `()` on the matches -- like `divOp()`. If you forget them, a simple assignment is made (and Scala will complain about unreachable code).
- And, as I said, if you are extracting something, then you need something inside those parenthesis. For instance, `"method ([%/])".r` would match `divOp(op)`, but not `divOp()`.

Answer (score 3):

Much the same as in Java. To escape a character in a regular expression, you prefix the character with `\`. However, backslash is also the escape character in standard Java/Scala strings, so to pass it through to the regular expression processing you must again prefix *it* with a backslash. You end up with something like:

```
scala> "+".matches("\\+")
res1 : Boolean = true
```

As James Iry points out in the comment below, Scala also has support for 'raw strings', enclosed in three quotation marks: `"""Raw string in which I don't need to escape things like \!"""` This allows you to avoid the second level of escaping, that imposed by Java/Scala strings. Note that you still need to escape any characters that are treated as special by the regular expression parser:

```
scala> "+".matches("""\+""")
res1 : Boolean = true
```

Comment: alternatively, Scala has "raw" strings which don't have special characters so you don't need extra escapes.  That makes regexes much more readable, usually.  E.g.  "+" matches """\+"""

Answer (score 0):

Escaping characters in Strings works like in Java.

If you have larger Strings which need a lot of escaping, consider Scala's `"""`.

E. g. `"""String without needing to escape anything \n \d"""`

If you put three `"""` around your regular expression you don't need to escape anything anymore.